# How can I show this simple inequality?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

Let us consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. For any $x\in 2^j \lambda_1 + [0,2^j)^n$ and $y\in 2^j \lambda_2 + [0,2^j)^n$, how can I show the following inequality,
$$ |x-y| \ge 2^{j-1}|\lambda_1 -\lambda_2|.$$
where $j$ is some integer. Moreover, can I replace $2^{j-1}$ by $2^j$? If then or not, why?

Comment: Do you have a proof for the special case of $n = 1$? Did you try to extend it, to $n = 2$ or arbitrary $n$? Please show some ideas so we know where you are stuck and how we can help you.

Comment: Actually, I don't have a proof. Since I can't sketch how I prove it, I tried to understand with graph and find infimum of $|x-y|$. However, all is fail. In other words, I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality fails already for $n=1$ and $j=0$. Indeed, let $x=1$ and $y=\frac 23$. Then $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=0$, so $|x-y|=\frac 13<\frac 12=\frac 12|\lambda_1-\lambda_2|$.